# String manipulation Ruby patterns

Tags: ruby, string

If I have a string: string = <.one><.two>three<.four>[:five] , how can I manipulate this string to remove everything inside the pattern "<..>". I would like my output to return; string = three[:five]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"<.one><.two>three<.four>[:five]".gsub(/<.+?>/, '')
```

Comment: Thats perfect thank you, I will accept this answer as soon as I can. Where can I learn more about the syntax inside the gsub? ie. /<.+?>/ . I assumed it would be something like this but couldnt get it right!

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):002:0> '<.one><.two>three<.four>[:five]'.gsub(/<[^>]*>/,'')
=> "three[:five]"
```